# changing spring security version s throwing error

Tags: spring, spring-security

I changed my spring security version from 3.2.3.RELEASE to 3.2.4.RELEASE and i am getting now the following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/application-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:313)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
```

any ideas..what can be the problem ?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using a dependency mechanism like Maven. If so, post your pom.xml-like file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class in exception is available in xml-apis JAR, and I suspect changing the version of spring-security caused conflicts in JAR resolution (in maven, I assume maven is used).  Check the maven dependency hierarchy and see if this JAR is included or not

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at classpath on your server. Be sure to add jar containing this class to the classpath. The class that you are missing can be found in xml-apis library, for example.